# How to avoid Type expected error while using WHEN?

Tags: android, kotlin, type-conversion, android-room, converters

I am trying to code a [type converter](https://adrianhall.github.io/android/2018/08/08/converting-types-with-room-and-kotlin/) between an Int and Priority. It is a Room database.

```
class PriorityConverter {
    companion object {
        @TypeConverter
        @JvmStatic
        fun intToPriority(number: Int?): Priority? = when (number) {
            is 1 -> Priority.Low
            is 2 -> Priority.Medium
            is 3 -> Priority.High
            else -> Priority.Low
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is I am getting the following error.

> Type expected

What might be the problem?

Comment: There is nothing more in the error message than that? :-(

Comment: No, that is all there is. When I try `is Int -> ...` then it works. Perhaps it has something to do with it being static and companion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`is` is for type comparison. For value comparison, just use the value:

```
class PriorityConverter {
    companion object {
        @TypeConverter
        @JvmStatic
        fun intToPriority(number: Int?): Priority? = when (number) {
            1 -> Priority.Low
            2 -> Priority.Medium
            3 -> Priority.High
            else -> Priority.Low
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, snap :). Thanks.